# Audio through Bluetooth Microphone through Jack (Galaxy S5)

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, headphone-jack

I'd like to receive audio from a phone call through my bluetooth earpiece. But I want to speak into a wired microphone.

Is this possible? Do I need a special app or specific specifications on my wired microphone or earpeice?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142693/use-phone-microphone-while-outputting-audio-through-bt-galaxy-s4 No resolution